# Matrix rotation algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, matrix

This is the [Matrix Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo) problem from [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/).

> You are given a 2D matrix, \$a\$, of dimension \$M×N\$ and a positive integer
>   \$R\$. You have to rotate the matrix R times and print the resultant
>   matrix. Rotation should be in anti-clockwise direction.
>
> Rotation of a \$4×5\$ matrix is represented by the following figure. Note
>   that in one rotation, you have to shift elements by one step only
>   (refer sample tests for more clarity).
>
> [image: Matrix Rotation Visualization]
>
> It is guaranteed that the minimum of \$M\$ and \$N\$ will be even.
>
> **Input**
>
> First line contains three space separated integers, \$M\$, \$N\$ and \$R\$, where \$M\$ is the number of rows, \$N\$ is number of columns in matrix, and \$R\$ is the number of times the matrix has to be rotated. Then \$M\$ lines follow, where each line contains \$N\$ space separated positive integers. These \$M\$ lines represent the matrix.
>
> **Output**
>
> Print the rotated matrix.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$2 \le M, N \le 300\$
> - \$1 \le R \le 10^9\$
> - \$\min(M, N) ≡ 0 \pmod 2\$
> - \$1 \le a_{ij} \le 10^8\$, where \$i \in [1\ldots M]\$ and \$j \in [1\ldots N]\$
>
> **Sample Input #00**
>
> ```
> 4 4 1
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> 9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16
> ```
>
> **Sample Output #00**
>
> ```
> 2 3 4 8
> 1 7 11 12
> 5 6 10 16
> 9 13 14 15
> ```
>
> **Sample Input #01**
>
> ```
> 4 4 2
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> 9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16
> ```
>
> **Sample Output #01**
>
> ```
> 3 4 8 12
> 2 11 10 16
> 1 7 6 15
> 5 9 13 14
> ```

Following is how I tried to solve the problem, but it runs just too slow:

```
from copy import deepcopy

aM, aN, R = map(int, input().split())

pivots = min(aM, aN)//2
refMat = []
baseMat = []

for i in range(aM):
    readInput = list(map(int, input().split()))
    baseMat.append(readInput)

refMat = deepcopy(baseMat)

for i in range(pivots):
    cLimit = (aN - 1) - i
    rLimit = (aM - 1) - i
    loopLength = (aM + aN - 2 - 4*i)*2 
    nbrOfRotations = R%loopLength

    for rotnIndex in range(nbrOfRotations):

        # Corner movements
        # Pivot
        refMat[i][i] = baseMat[i][i + 1]
        # Column End
        refMat[i][cLimit] = baseMat[i + 1][cLimit]
        # Row End
        refMat[rLimit][i] = baseMat[rLimit - 1][i]
        # Pivot diagonal
        refMat[rLimit][cLimit] = baseMat[rLimit][cLimit - 1]

        # Top movement
        for j in range(i+1, cLimit):
            refMat[i][j] = baseMat[i][j + 1]

        # Bottom movement
        for j in range(i+1, cLimit):
            refMat[rLimit][j] = baseMat[rLimit][j - 1]

        # Left movement
        for j in range(i+1, rLimit):
            refMat[j][i] = baseMat[j - 1][i]

        # Right movement
        for j in range(i+1, rLimit):
            refMat[j][cLimit] = baseMat[j + 1][cLimit]

        baseMat = deepcopy(refMat)

for i in refMat:
    for e in i:
        print(e, end = " ")
    print()
```

**Note**: No advanced libraries such as NumPy, SciPy etc. are allowed. However, I would love to know if they offer a better workaround.

Comment: It doesn’t seem that slow to me. Are there particular cases that are causing you problems?

Comment: @alexwlchan, it does become slow when the inputs, for example, are of the dimension `rows = 136, columns = 240 and rotations = 212131`

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to pre-compute the new position of any element, instead of shifting them around. Or some other better/efficient way to get this done. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: There isn't really a need to actually move the elements, just update the starting one for each layer, and all the rest just follow behind it.
As an example, if you are rotating

1 2
3 4

you can just start later on (at 2) and print each answer from there

Comment: @spyr03, that sounds interesting! Can you please elaborate a little more probably with a pseudo-code.

Comment: @BenSoorajM it may take a while to do the full code for me, I'll get back to you in a couple of days

Comment: @BenSoorajM I posted a question because I wasn't happy with the code, but it has the easiest way I found of doing it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99073/matrix-rotation-alg

Comment: Did you consider moving a whole row/column at a time rather than element by element? You could use some modular arithmetic to figure out how much of a given row/column could be wholesale copied and moved to it's rotated place.

Comment: this smells like a exam question :)

Comment: Well no, rather from a programming challenge. I cleared only 3/4th of the test cases. Time constraints :D

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers, or comment on why you don't find any of the current answers good enough for acception.

Comment: @holroy : _Last seen Aug 28_

Comment: @greybeard, I know, just trying to see if we're able to get a sign off for the question... Not very likely, but worth a little try... I also have another idea, but it'll take some time to implement, and I would like to know if this still is an interesting problem statement before using several hours on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Much better algorithm in my view:

Consider first matrix example

```
1   2  3  4
5   6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16

R=rotations
```

convert in 2 circles (at least either M or N is even, thus there is no single center point):

```
c1 = [1,2,3,4,8,12,16,15,14,13,9,5]
c2 = [6,7,11,10]
```

for each position calculate actual value:

```
c1’[i] = c1[(i+R)%c1.length]
c2’[i] = c2[(i+R)%c2.length]
…
```

The number of circles is `min(M, N)/2` hence this strange constraint in the task :)

This solves in linear \$O(M+N)\$ complexity rather than your cubic \$O(M\cdot N\cdot R)\$ complexity.

EDIT: of course revert the circles back to the matrix format.

Comment: Is `c2’[i]` a typo? It's not really correct syntax.

Comment: It is pseudo syntax and means derived. This algorithm is not language specific and c2_derived I considered too long :) keeps you awake :P I also hope, that c1.length will be extracted in a local variable, that cN will be an array and so on…

Comment: yes sorry I didn't follow it at first. I could tell it was partly psuedo code I just wasn't familiar with the derived notation in the middle of what's normal Python syntax otherwise (ie `c1[i]` is valid)

Comment: How would you generate the original `c1` and `c2` array? Do you have a general formula for when the number of circles increases?

Comment: I am not quite sure, what you are asking for. How to calculate the number of circles I wrote `min(M,N)/2`. The initial creation of `c_n` (can I use the math env in comments also?) looks trivial to me ;). Would you like to see the start of it?