# Matrix rotation algorithm - follow-up

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, matrix

In a response to [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98540/matrix-rotation-algorithm) I wrote a solution in Python. It passed all the test cases given, so I would like help making it more pythonic and reducing the almost repeated lines.

[Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo) to the source of the question on HackerRank.

```
# input
M, N, rotations = map(int, input().split())
matrix = []
for row in range(M):
    matrix.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

# flatten the rings into a list
layers = int(min(N, M)/2)
ring = [[] for layer in range(layers)]

for level in range(layers):
    top = (N-1) - 2 * level
    side = (M-1) - 2 * level
    for row in range(top):  # right
        ring[level].append(matrix[level][level + row])
    for col in range(side):  # down
        ring[level].append(matrix[level + col][level + top])
    for row in range(top):  # left
        ring[level].append(matrix[level + side][level + top - row])
    for col in range(side):  # up
        ring[level].append(matrix[level + side - col][level]) 

# rotate each layer
for level in range(layers):
        r = rotations % len(ring[level])
        ring[level] = ring[level][r:] + ring[level][:r]

# fill the array with the rotated elements
for level in range(layers):
    top = (N-1) - 2 * level
    side = (M-1) - 2 * level
    for row in range(top):
        matrix[level][level + row] = ring[level].pop(0)  # right
    for col in range(side):
        matrix[level + col][level + top] = ring[level].pop(0)  # down
    for row in range(top):
        matrix[level + side][level + top - row] = ring[level].pop(0)  # left
    for col in range(side):
        matrix[level + side - col][level] = ring[level].pop(0)  # up

# print the rotated matrix
for row in range(M):
    for col in range(N):
        print(matrix[row][col], "", end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the answers, or comment on why you don't find any of the current answers good enough for acception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### List comprehensions

Whenever you see a list initialization to `[]`,
later filled in by `.append(...)` calls in a loop,
consider rewriting with a list comprehension.
For example:

> ```
> matrix = []
> for row in range(M):
>     matrix.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
> ```

Can be rewritten on a single line:

```
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(M)]
```

Note that I renamed `row` to `_`,
this is a common convention when then loop variable is unused.

Another example of that is this list comprehension later in your code:

> ```
> ring = [[] for layer in range(layers)]
> ```

Like earlier, rename `layer` to `_`:

```
ring = [[] for _ in range(layers)]
```

#### Integer division with `//`

Instead of this:

> ```
> layers = int(min(N, M)/2)
> ```

Another, a more natural way to achieve the same effect using integer division with `//`:

```
layers = min(N, M) // 2
```

#### Coding style

The body of this for-loop is overindented:

> ```
> # rotate each layer
> for level in range(layers):
>         r = rotations % len(ring[level])
>         ring[level] = ring[level][r:] + ring[level][:r]
> ```

Possibly it's a result of the copy-pasting?
Either way,
a [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) checker would catch this.
It's recommended to use four spaces for an indent level,
and to use only spaces and never tabs for indenting code.

#### Reducing duplicated code

The current implementation works like this:

1. put each layer into `ring`
2. rotate the values in each layer in `ring`
3. overwrite the layers in the matrix from `ring`

Step 1 and 3 have very similar code, as you yourself noticed.
One way to reduce that is to implement shifting in-place,
without using the additional storage `ring`,
by doing something like this (\$k\$ is the number of rotations):

1. save the first \$k\$ items in a list
2. overwrite the \$i\$-th values by the \$(i+k)\$-th values. The last \$k\$ values will come from the values we saved in the previous step.

Easier said than done? Yes. Calculating the \$(i + k)\$-th position will be tricky.

I'd say your original implementation with the similar lines is fine:
it's easy to understand, and it passed the tests anyway.